# Leer un fichero y almacenar los datos en diferentes vectores

Tags: dev-c++

Tenemos un fichero del tipo:
Nombre
1 244 3 4 52
Texto   Texto

Queremos almacenar los diferentes datos 1, 244, 3, 4, 52, Texto y Texto todos en diferentes vectores de una misma estructura. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido ¿Que intentaste? Agrégalo a la pregunta [editandola](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/577728/edit)

Comment: Recuerda que tu pregunta no debe parecer [un ticket para desarrollo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento, y el problema _específico_ que has tenido.